# How can I create custom button in post.php

Tags: posts, customization, publish, buttons

I want to create a custom button to go the customize.php. I want to create it here
[image: I want to create it here]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **media_buttons** action for it. Check below code.

```
add_action('media_buttons', 'add_my_media_button');
function add_my_media_button(){
 echo '<a href="'.get_site_url().'/wp-admin/customize.php" class="button button-default">Customize</a>';
}
```

Hope this will helps you.

Thanks!